# Does R save objects of a function in memory?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

I have a function that calls a subset of data from MSSQL and then plots a histogram. The dataset is about 1 million records.

I was wondering if the function saves the data into memory after the plot is displayed?

Lets say the data is 200 MB and I have 1000 MB of ram.

After I run my function does the data take up 200 MB (800 MB left) or it returns to 1000 MB?

If it does take up 200 MB after running, how do I generate the plot without eating up all my memory.

My function:

```
echeckvscc <- function(year) {
  library(RODBC)
  library(ggplot2)
  myconn <- odbcConnect("SQLServer")
  query = paste("select * 
              from PaymentAnalysis 
              where statusdesc = 'Successful'
              and year = ", year, 
              "and PayMethodDesc2 in ('Credit Card','eCheck') 
              and TransType is not null 
              and TotTransAmt > 0")

  a <- ggplot(sqlQuery(myconn, query = query),aes(x = month, fill = PayMethodDesc2 ))
  a <- a + geom_histogram(position = "dodge", binwidth = .5, origin = -0.25) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)

  odbcClose(myconn)

  return(a)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In general, functions clear everything after finishing execution. However there are many exceptions, and without seeing your function, we cannot be sure.

Comment: @jeremycg thanks, I've included my function to the post.

Comment: Activate `gcinfo(TRUE)` and you can observe garbage collections. If one does not occur after your function, prompt it with `gc(verbose=TRUE)`.

Comment: @A.Webb it seems like i am collecting a lot, how do i delete the garbage?

Comment: collection = deletion (free to be used again)

Comment: @A.Webb just to confirm, by adding gc(verbose=TRUE) at the end of my function will delete garbage?

Comment: If it can, yes, though you rarely need to call it explicitly, garbage collection occurs automatically as needed. Using `gc(verbose=TRUE)` is done in an interactive session primarily for information purposes.